# PHP foreach with include not updating past 1st iteration

Tags: php, foreach

I have a simple PHP foreach loop that generates some HTML, and as part of this it includes another file that generates some Javascript code. The include file echoes a variable that is set at the top of the foreach loop, but it is displaying the same value for all items in the loop.

Here's a cutdown version of the foreach loop:

```
foreach($records as $record){
            $recid = $record->getRecordId();

             if ($type == 'A') {
                 // set some variables
                 include('displayPopover.php');
            } elseif ($type == 'B') {
                 // set some variables
                 include('displayPopover.php');
}
```

The displayPopover.php includes this:

```
<p><strong><?php echo $recid ?></strong></p>
```

When I view the page in the browser it's showing the same value for the  string. Everything else in the foreach loop is updating for each record but not the code in the include file for some reason after the first iteration.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need a separate `.php` file for this?

Comment: A point of interest, `$records` contains, what? An array with single key?

Comment: Just use `include_once` instead of `include`

Comment: um just weird, multiple questions - but starting with what's `$records`

Comment: @Irvin the question is why the code doesn't work, and not about the need for a separate file.

Comment: Sorry I simplified my code sample too much - the foreach loop also includes an If/Else If inside it which sets additional variables and then includes the file. I've updated my foreach sample to reflect this.

Comment: are you using this variable inside js??

Comment: $records contains an array of database records - there's no issue there and I'm referencing items from the array successfully. I'm using a separate file for organisation/readability - wasn't aware of any issues with using it in a foreach loop before.

Comment: @NishanthMatha - no I"m just doing a echo of the variable inside some HTML code

Comment: next time show the "real" code please

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic The mere fact that OP uses a separate file might be causing the problem so I am asking why is there a need for it.